# Copy Operation under site '<site name>' failed in the Content and Structure tool. Details in ULS logs

Tags: 2013, site

I'm trying to copy a site through Manage Content and Structure.
It startes of fine, but at some point it fails with the following message:

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

In ULS I have a critical entry with the message:

> Copy Operation under site 'TestNY' failed in the Content and Structure tool. Details in ULS logs

and an exception 2 ms before:

```
LRO - An exception was thrown by the DoWork method of a LongRunningOperation System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.EventReceiverSerializer.UpdateEventReceiver(SPEventReceiverDefinition eventReceiver, XmlElement eventReceiverData)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.EventReceiverSerializer.SetObjectData(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, ISurrogateSelector selector)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.WebSerializer.UpdateEventReceivers(String tagReceivers, SPWeb web, SerializationInfoHelper infoHelper, StreamingContext context, ISurrogateSelector selector)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.WebSerializer.SetObjectData(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, ISurrogateSelector selector)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.CallSetObjectData(Object obj, SerializationInfo objectData, ISerializationSurrogate surrogate, ISurrogateSelector selector)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.ParseObject(Type objectType, Boolean isChildObject)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.DeserializeObject(Type objectType, Boolean isChildObject, DeploymentObject envelope)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ObjectSerializer.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.DeserializeObjects()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.Run()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.DeploymentWrapper.Copy(String[] sourceSmtObjectIds, String destSmtObjectId)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WebControls.CopyObjects.Copy()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WebControls.CopyObjects.DoWork()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Diagnostics.FirstChanceHandler.ExceptionFilter(Boolean fRethrowException, TryBlock tryBlock, FilterBlock filter, CatchBlock catchBlock, FinallyBlock finallyBlock) StackTrace: 
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Native.dll: (sig=678c0f87-966f-4d99-9c94-b49e788d2672|2|microsoft.office.server.native.pdb, offset=131CE)
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Native.dll: (offset=21BE5)
```

Comment: Are you locking down access to the site while you are doing this, or  doing when you know there are no changes?  Do you know if you have any customization installed (Bamboo, Kwizcom, or anything else).

Comment: I have found that its an EventRechiver thats causing the problem.
If i delete it or deactivate the feature adding it, copy works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting a custom EventRechiver solved this problem.